# How to use \def command in \uput

Tags: macros, pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent,pstricks-add,multido} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}

\def\stuff1{Môi trường Vật lý}
\def\stuff2{Sự lãng mạn}
\def\stuff3{Sự nghiệp}
\def\stuff4{Gia đình/Bạn bè}
\def\stuff5{Tài chính}
\def\stuff6{Phát triển bản thân}
\def\stuff7{Sức khỏe}
\def\stuff8{Niềm vui/Giải trí}

\psChart[userColor={cyan,green,red,blue,teal,brown,gray,pink}] 
 {20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20}{}{2}
\multido{\r=-1.75+0.5,\n=8+-1}{8}{
     \psset{fillstyle=solid,dotstyle=square,dotscale=2}
     \def\a{3.5}
     \psdot[fillcolor=chartFillColor\n](\a,\r)
     \uput[0](\a,\r){\stuff\n}  }
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{document}
```

It produces:

[image]

How to its produces as the following:

[image]

One related question:

Why the result of compiling {20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20} as {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10} or {45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence specified as part of the mandatory argument for `\psChart` represents the proportions of the total pie being used for each segment. So, `{20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20}` will use the same proportions as `{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}` and `{45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45}` (or 12.5% each). You'll notice a difference in the pie slice sizes if you specify differing numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}

  \expandafter\def\csname stuff1\endcsname{First}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff2\endcsname{Second}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff3\endcsname{Third}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff4\endcsname{Fourth}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff5\endcsname{Fifth}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff6\endcsname{Sixth}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff7\endcsname{Seventh}
  \expandafter\def\csname stuff8\endcsname{Eighth}

  \psChart[
    userColor={cyan,green,red,blue,teal,brown,gray,pink}
  ]
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}{}{2}

  \def\a{3.5}
  \multido{\r=-1.75+0.5,\n=8+-1}{8}{
    \psset{fillstyle=solid,dotstyle=square,dotscale=2}
    \psdot[fillcolor=chartFillColor\n](\a,\r)
    \uput[0](\a,\r){\csname stuff\n\endcsname}
  }

  \psframe(3,-2)(5.5,2)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you compact the syntax of "\expandafter\def\csname stuff1\endcsname{First}" such as \expandafter\def\csname ... \endcsname{...} only used 1 time ?

Comment: @chishimotoji: Sure. Check out [this code](https://pastebin.com/5yaXUcbS).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newcent,pstricks-add,multido} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\def\stuff#1{%
    \ifcase #1
    \or {Môi trường Vật lý}
    \or {Sự lãng mạn}
    \or {Sự nghiệp}
    \or {Gia đình/Bạn bè}
    \or {Tài chính}
    \or {Phát triển bản thân}
    \or {Sức khỏe}
    \or {Niềm vui/Giải trí}
    \fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(10,5)  
\psChart[userColor={cyan,green,red,blue,teal,brown,gray,pink}]{20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20}{}{2}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,dotstyle=square,dotscale=2}%
\def\a{3.5}%
\multido{\r=-1.75+0.5,\n=8+-1}{8}{%
  \psdot[fillcolor=chartFillColor\n](\a,\r) \uput[0](\a,\r){\stuff{\n}}%
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With good pst-tools package and \psRegisterList{Name}{value list}  \<Name>{Index}. I can also get the same result... A wonderful package....